# Server Socket Input Stream returning null before disconnect

Tags: java, sockets, while-loop

I am trying to deal with client disconnects in a simple java application that sends chat messages using a client and a server.

Here's the problem

```
public void run() {
    try {
        System.out.println("Client Connected");
        String inputLine;

        while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(inputLine);
            theServer.handle(inputLine, this);
        }
        out.close();
        in.close();
        socket.close();
        System.out.println("Client Disconnected");

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

With this code here, it runs the while loop while the input line is not null. If it is null then it will stop looping and close the in and out streams as well as the socket. Now, this is all working fine apart from the output in the console is this:

```
Client Connected
null
Client(/127.0.0.1): null
null
Client(/127.0.0.1): null
null
Client(/127.0.0.1): null
null
Client(/127.0.0.1): null
Client Disconnected
```

I can't figure out why the loop would keep looping even when the input is null!! It seems to take a while to realise that it's null before exiting the loop. I need it to exit straight away without a delay.

Any help would be appreciated,

shadrxninga

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only explanations that I can think of are:

- `in.readLine()` is returning the string `"null"` (possibly with trailing whitespace),
- `in` refers to some custom stream or reader wrapper whose `readLine()` method is doing something weird, or
- this is not the code that you are actually executing.

You say:

> *"It seems to take a while to realise that it's null before exiting the loop."*

This is a "voodoo programming" explanation.  It cannot possibly be correct unless there's a bug in your Java implementation.  And that is *extremely* unlikely.

Comment: The in refers to this:
  in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(socket.getInputStream()));

Comment: I know that that what I said is not possible, it's just what seems to be happening. The code is executing, as the code is printing the information to the console.

Comment: So - the only solution that I think will work is the first one you gave me.

Comment: OK ... that leaves the first and third explanations.

Comment: Before the while loop try printing out the `inputLine` string. If it says null, then I think your data is not traveling via your socket.

Comment: @shadrxninga You might need to check for both `null` and the string `"null"`. But I think it would be a better idea to look into why the client sends the string `"null"`, as it indicates that the client is trying to use a null pointer or reference.

Comment: Well, here is some other strange thing. If you send a message to the servers input stream, then when you disconnect it exits the loop when it is supposed to.

Comment: @Joachim Pileborg Thanks, the client wasn't disconnecting properly and was sending null through it's out stream. It's all working now.

Answer (score 0):

Well it looks like that the null being returned is in the form string so that's why it's behaving this way.